# Getting records based on latest date

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm quite new to SQL and I'm trying to filter the latest date record (`DateTime` column) for each unique ID present in the table.

Sample data: there are 2 unique IDs (16512) and (76513).

| DateTime | ID | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-26T10:39:54.9770238 | 16512 | Still a work in Progress |
| 2021-04-29T12:46:12.8277807 | 16512 | Still working on it |
| 2021-03-21T10:39:54.9770238 | 76513 | Still a work in Progress |
| 2021-04-20T12:46:12.8277800 | 76513 | Still working on project |

Desired result (get last row of each ID based on the DateTime column):

| DateTime | ID | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-29T12:46:12.8277807 | 16512 | Still working on it |
| 2021-04-20T12:46:12.8277800 | 76513 | Still working on project |

My query:

```
SELECT MAX(DateTime), ID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY DateTime, ID
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT max(DateTime), ID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` here

```
with d as (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by Id order by DataTime desc)rn
)
select Datetime, Id, Notes
from d
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state a particular database but if you are using Postgres then you can use its `DISTINCT ON` and is often the [fastest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/189090) if the size of your groups is not too big (in your case this is the size of tasks that have the same id).

Here's an example. Please note I've excluded your notes column for brevity but it will work if you include it and will give you the output you desire above.

```
create temporary table tasks (
  id int,
  created_at date,
);

insert into tasks(id, created_at) values
(16512, '2021-03-26'), 
(16512, '2021-04-29'),
(76513, '2021-03-21'), 
(76513, '2021-04-20')
;


select 
         distinct on (id)
         id, 
       created_at
from tasks
order by id, created_at desc

/*
  id   | created_at
-------+------------
 16512 | 2021-04-29
 76513 | 2021-04-20
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned `row_number` is one of the method solving your problem. You tagged *databricks* in your question, so let me show you another option that you can implement with Spark SQL using `last` function from aggregate functions pool.

In refrence to the spark documentation:
[last(expr[, isIgnoreNull]) - Returns the last value of expr for a group of rows. If isIgnoreNull is true, returns only non-null values](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#last).

Note that:

> The function is non-deterministic because its results depends on the order of the rows which may be non-deterministic after a shuffle.

In your example:

```
%sql

WITH cte AS (
 SELECT * 
 FROM my_table
 ORDER BY DateTime asc
)
SELECT Id, last(DateTime) AS DateTime, last(Notes) as Notes
FROM cte
GROUP BY Id
```

Similarly, you can use `first` function to obtain the first record in a sorted dataset.

Check if that works for you.